# Is there any way to label albums and query those albums based on the label?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What I'm looking to do is query all albums that are labeled or grouped together. So my first question is, is there a way to group or label a set of albums? And Second is there a way to query all albums that are labeled or grouped together? Any insight on this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The only label you can give to an album is it's name and there is no way to "group" albums together.

The only real way to group albums together is to look at the type -

```
/USER_ID/albums/?fields=type
```

This will show you if it is a

- wall album - an album containing photo's you uploaded and posted on your timeline
- mobile album - an album of photos uploaded from a mobile device
- profile album - an album of profile pictures
- normal album - one that was created manually by the user

There might be more types but not on my account :P So I have no way of checking at the moment. The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/) specifies profile, mobile, wall, normal or album... Not too sure what an album of type album is...but there it is!

Comment: Thanks Lix, I did come across this. Was just hoping there was a better way haha.